# How to get current route in the midst of a Views AJAX request

Tags: 8, routes, ajax, views

I need to conditionally pass contextual filter values to a view based on the current route and am attempting to do so in hook_views_pre_view. This is the result of using AJAX via views_infinite_scroll and losing the contextual filters that I initially pass in programmatically.

On the initial request, the following works great for getting the current route in hook_views_pre_view:

```
$current_route_match = \Drupal::getContainer()->get('current_route_match');
$current_route_match->getRouteName();
```

However, when I hit the 'Load more' button supplied by views_infinite_scroll, the route name of the current route match is 'views.ajax'. While I understand that this is technically the request's route, I need to know the original route, or from where the request was made.

After digging around, I noticed that $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] had the right path, but the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) says:

> Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Comment: False alarm. While accessing the "original route" in the midst of an AJAX request would be helpful, I discovered that my problem was actually a misunderstanding of Views. I have two contextual filters for a view and was passing in `false` as the first in an effort to not filter by any value. For some reason this worked on the initial page request but ended up evaluating to `null` on the subsequent AJAX requests, being ignored completely. This bug caused me to think that contextual filters  - applied programmatically - did not persist through multiple requests. Luckily I was wrong :)

Answer (score 6):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'views.ajax') {
    $previousUrl = \Drupal::request()->server->get('HTTP_REFERER');
    $fake_request = Request::create($previousUrl);
    $url_object = \Drupal::service('path.validator')->getUrlIfValid($fake_request->getRequestUri());
    if ($url_object) {
      $route_name = $url_object->getRouteName();
      // Do something with $route_name;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `$previousUrl` can be null, e.g. when is the first page visited by the user. With PHP 8.1+ it causes the warming `Deprecated function: parse_url(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($url) of type string is deprecated`. It may be better to add a check on the existence of `$previousUrl`